# SDL_Surface pointer withing class becoming NULL

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

My SDL_Surface within my own defined class, Actor, is returning to NULL after I load the SDL_Surface. After much console output and using GDB to find where the error might possibly be. The Actor class contains a pointer to an SDL_Surface and Actor::getSurface returns the pointer to the SDL_Surface.

Of course, you believe more code displayed will help solve the problem, I would be happy to share.

My program output is:

```
--Surface was loaded.
Surface is NULL after loading.
```

I cut out the unimportant parts of the code.

main.cpp:

```
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

Actor sprite;
sprite.loadSurface("images/bg.bmp");
if( sprite.getSurface() == NULL )
  std::clog << "Surface is NULL after loading." << std::endl;
```

Actor.cpp

```
bool Actor::loadSurface(std::string t_filename)
{
  std::clog << "-ACTOR " << m_id << " LOADSURFACE" << std::endl;
  SDL_Surface * loadedImage = NULL;
  m_surface = NULL;

  loadedImage = IMG_Load( t_filename.c_str() );
  if( loadedImage != NULL )
  {
    std::clog << "--Surface was loaded." << std::endl;
    m_surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha( loadedImage );
    SDL_FreeSurface( loadedImage );
    return true;
  }
  std::clog << "--Surface was not loaded." << std::endl;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Show us the entire Actor class

Comment: Actor.cpp http://pastebin.com/0PVhuYuU

Comment: Actor.h http://pastebin.com/ZzFsTTUF

Comment: or could be `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` failed, it returns null: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha

Comment: Yes, it returns NULL. Thanks, this gives me a better idea where to look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha` returns `NULL`.

This could happen if you didn't call `SDL_SetVideoMode` before trying to convert the image, validate that this is the case.

Another option that would cause the `NULL` return value is if you ran out of memory.

Comment: I set the video mode in the constructor. Thanks for the help. I can narrow down where the problem is coming from.

Comment: SetVideoMode should only be called once, I suggest moving it next to your `SDL_Init`

Comment: Shouldn't SDL_SetVideoMode be used to change the width, height, and flags of the video screen?

Comment: Yes, for your "rendering window", and returns the surface on which you will blit your sprites. It should therefore be called when initializing the "video" part of your engine. If the call is in the constructor of a `RenderingManager` that gets constructed AFTER `SDL_Init` and before an `Actor` is created, you should be fine, if every actor calls the function, you'll have a problem!